# Clicklistner in webview

Tags: android

The question can be a little vague, I have created a webview and showing the webpage of the URL which I get from some server. Now When i navigate to different pages , On one page there is only a button which will send me a different URL , I need that when user is on that page and click on that button the webview should hide and user continue other operation. I have read that addJavascriptInterface is needed to do this , can anyone tell me if this is possible and how to achieve this , any good tutorial will work.

I also tried this but of no use

```
 wv.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            HitTestResult result = wv.getHitTestResult();
            if (result.getType() == HitTestResult.UNKNOWN_TYPE) {
                Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage();
                wv.requestFocusNodeHref(msg);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Have you read this: http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#HandlingNavigation

Comment: yes I tried doin something similar to this   @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

        view.loadUrl(url);

        return false;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    topupWV.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        topupWV.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

                    if (url.startsWith("XXXXX")) {

                        try {
                            URL urls = new URL(url);
                            query = urls.getQuery();



                        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }





                        return true;
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                    super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

                }

                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                }

            });


}
```

Answer (score -2):

you can do something like this for detecting click within a webview

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                if (isNetworkConnected()) {
                    //DO YOU OPERATION HERE
                } 
                return true;
            }
        });
```